# AngularJS Jasmine error 'Controller is not a function' when instantiated with arguments

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I have been doing angularJS for a while now (without tests) but I want to do it properly! I have a controller defined like so

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .controller('CarehomeListCtrl', ['$scope', 'carehomesDataService', carehomeListCtrl]);


function carehomeListCtrl($scope, carehomesDataService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.carehomeCollection = [];

    vm.activate = activate;


    function activate() {
        vm.carehomeCollection = carehomesDataService.getAllCarehomes();
    }

    activate();
}
})();
```

and then my spec

```
   describe("Carehomes tests", function () {
    var $scopeConstructor, $controllerConstructor;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {

        $controllerConstructor = $controller;
        $scopeConstructor = $rootScope;
    }));

    describe("CarehomeListCtrl", function () {
        var ctrl, dataService, scope;
        function createController() {
            return $controllerConstructor('CarehomeListCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                carehomesDataService: dataService
            });

        }
        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            scope = $scopeConstructor.$new();
            dataService =$injector.get('carehomesDataService') ;
        }));

        it("should have a carehomesCollection array", function () {
            ctrl = createController();
            expect(ctrl.carehomesCollection).not.toBeNull();
        });

        it("should have 3 items in carehomesCollection array when load is called", function () {
            ctrl = createController();
            expect(ctrl.carehomeCollection.length).toBe(3);
        });
    });


});
```

The problem here is that the call to instantiate my controller fails with error whenever I call it with any arguments whether an empty object {} or just $scope : scope} so I know the problem is not carehomesDataService.

> Result StackTrace:    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CarehomeListCtrl' is not
>   a function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ng/areq?p0=CarehomeListCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

However, if I instantiate that controller like this `$controllerConstructor('CarehomeListCtrl');` without arguments, it gets instantiated. I'm stumped!

carehomesDataService is a custom service I have written but it's own tests pass and it is correctly injected into the controller in the application.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

**Note: I do not quite agree with defining properties on the controller as the view model instead of on $scope but I am following Jesse Liberty's pluralsight course and that's how he does it....plus injecting scope isn't quite working right now which is annoying. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Can you replicate it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/iKI9XL6Ca5AIU6LaAYsd

Comment: Hi @tasseKATT, it looks like you've already replicated it in the plunkr and it seems to work! But all I see on my screens is failing tests and I can't figure out why, I'll copy the code from the plunkr just incase I am missing something and I'll come back to you. Thanks

Comment: Ok, maybe someone could explain to me how karma works, because I've left my code for a whole day, come back and exited karma, closed my command line window, restarted it and run the tests again and this time the tests pass. I'm not so comfy with that because as it is I cannot tell what caused the problem and as such I cannot tell if it will happen again....but at least for now I can continue my work. Thanks @tasseKATT

Comment: I finally figured it though I don't know why but I am using Karma which is meant to watch my js files and rerun the tests. If I modify the spec files it runs ok, but whenever I modify the controller, then I have to kill karma and restart it otherwise I get the above error. I have no idea why this is but at least now I know what caused the problem.

Comment: Ah, glad you found the cause.

Comment: I'm following the same course!!! Let's see if your solution solves my problem also!... Nope sadly not :(